# Should we have doctor-who-classic and doctor-who-2005 tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was just thinking about getting to questions regarding classic Doctor Who, then I realized its need. Should we have these tags?

**Update:**
I never told anything about splitting. Existing "doctor-who" tag should continue to exist because there are generic Doctor Who questions addressing the whole canon.

Answer (score 9):

Splitting the tags should be prompted by a need. The need shouldn't be "Ooh, it'd be neater and more taxonomically satisfying to have this sub-distinction", but more like "We, the community of NewWho fans, are constantly annoyed by OldWho questions that we don't care about", and vice versa. I don't think this is the case - there's a lot of overlap both between fans of the two eras, and by the content of the answers themselves - many NewWho questions are perfectly served by an OldWho answer.

I think the one tag, with its ~725 questions, is fine as it is.

Comment: Notably in terms of canon level there's no distinction between nuWho and oldWho. They're all part of the same continuity.